# nodejs unit testing framework that does not require an external test runner

Tags: node.js, unit-testing

All of the unit testing frameworks that I know of / can find require a test runner.

They all require you to globally install and run some program that runs your tests. Is there a well supported testing framework that can run as an npm `require()` ?

I need one like this because I want to be able to debug my tests, and it is *much* easier for me to do this though [webstorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/). Also, the project I'm working on is very small and I don't want to get fancy

Answer (score 0):

The node.js project itself simply uses the built-in `assert` module and JavaScript exceptions. They have a fairly straightforward script that runs every `.js` file in a directory tree and if the file doesn't throw any exceptions, the test is considered passing. You could use something like that.

However, although most frameworks do have a command line runner, you absolutely never need to install them (or *anything*) with `-g`. If you understand the basic concept of the unix `PATH` environment variable, you can `npm install --save-dev mocha` (for example) and then run your tests with `./node_modules/.bin/mocha`. No `-g` required.

See also http://peterlyons.com/problog/2012/09/managing-per-project-interpreters-and-the-path